# Issue in establishing a connection between the server and client-side programs in an Inter-Process Communication practice program using Named Pipes

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex, ipc, semaphore

I have developed a Windows Forms application using C# with the goal of implementing Inter-Process Communication (IPC) between two separate solutions. Each solution has a component for sending and receiving messages, and the aim is to create something resembling a messaging app but with IPC-based communication.

Please keep in mind that my intention behind this project is to create a learning exercise for understanding IPC.

However, I am encountering an issue where messages cannot be sent from the server to the client or vice versa, and the project doesn't seem to be functioning correctly. I'm not sure if the problem lies in the Named Pipe communication setup or in how I'm managing the threads within the application.

this is Server side Code:

```
public partial class serverForm : Form
    {
        private NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = null;
        private StreamReader streamReader = null;
        private StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
        private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(initialCount: 1, maximumCount: 1);
        private bool startWork = false;
        private String sendMsg = null;

        public serverForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void serverForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           new Thread(() =>
            {
                StartServer();
            }).Start();
        }

        private void StartServer()
        {
            pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut);

            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

            startWork = true;

            streamReader = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
            streamWriter = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => StreamReader());
            thread2.Start();

            while (pipeServer.IsConnected) 
            {
                if (semaphore.WaitOne())
                {
                    if (sendMsg != null && sendMsg.Length > 0)
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(sendMsg);
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        sendMsg = null;
                    }
                    semaphore.Release();
                }                

                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        private void StreamWrite(String msg)
        {
            //StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);
            //writer.Write(msg);
            //writer.Close();

            //streamWriter.WriteLine(msg);
            //streamWriter.Flush();

            while (pipeServer.IsConnected)
            {
                if (semaphore.WaitOne())
                {
                    sendMsg = msg;
                    semaphore.Release();

                    break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }

        private void StreamReader()
        {
            while (pipeServer != null && pipeServer.IsConnected)
            {
                string data = streamReader.ReadLine();

                if (data != null)
                {
                    messagesTxt.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        messagesTxt.Text += "Client: " + data + "\r\n";
                    }));
                }
            }
        }

        private void sendMessageTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void sendMessageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (startWork)
            {
                String msg = sendMessageTxt.Text;
                if (msg != null && msg.Length > 0)
                {
                    messagesTxt.Text += "Server: " + msg + "\r\n";
                    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => StreamWrite(msg));
                    thread1.Start();
                    
                    sendMessageTxt.Text = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Connection is not valid");
            }
        }

        private void sendMessageTxt_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                sendMessageBtn_Click(sender, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is Client side code:

```
public partial class clientForm : Form
    {
        private NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = null;
        private StreamReader streamReader = null;
        private StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
        private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(initialCount: 1, maximumCount: 1);
        private bool startWork = false;
        private String sendMsg = null;
        private string serverMessage;
        private string defaultClientMessage = "No Message Yet";
        public clientForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void clientForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                StartServer();
            }).Start();
        }

        private void StartServer()
        {
            pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut);

            pipeClient.Connect();

            startWork = true;


            streamReader = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
            streamWriter = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => StreamReader(pipeClient));
            thread2.Start();

            while (pipeClient.IsConnected)
            {
                if (semaphore.WaitOne())
                {
                    if (sendMsg != null && sendMsg.Length > 0)
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(sendMsg);
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        sendMsg = null;
                    }
                    semaphore.Release();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        private void StreamReader(NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient)
        {
            while (pipeClient != null && pipeClient.IsConnected)
            {
                string data = streamReader.ReadLine();

                if (data != null)
                {
                    messagesTxt.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        messagesTxt.Text += "Client: " + data + "\r\n";
                    }));
                }
            }
        }

        private void StreamWrite(NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient, String msg)
        {
            while (pipeClient.IsConnected)
            {
                if (semaphore.WaitOne())
                {
                    sendMsg = msg;
                    semaphore.Release();

                    break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }

        private void sendMessageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (startWork)
            {
                String msg = sendMessageTxt.Text;
                if (msg != null && msg.Length > 0)
                {
                    messagesTxt.Text += "Client: " + msg + "\r\n";
                    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => StreamWrite(pipeClient, msg));
                    thread1.Start();
                    

                    sendMessageTxt.Text = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Connection is not valid");
            }
        }

        private void sendMessageTxt_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                sendMessageBtn_Click(sender, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have limited experience in programming and using various techniques such as Named Pipes and IPC. Therefore, I want to express my gratitude in advance for the time you're going to invest and for your guidance in helping me.

Comment: Using Thread.Sleep from my experience is an indicator there might be timing issues wich may be solved better by other means like blocking collections ... then another thing _which is probably unrelated_: I'd recommend to use the pattern `sem.WaitOne(); try{ ... } finally { sem.Release(); }`

Comment: Looking at the code, on first glance, I'd _suspect_ a threading issue more than an IPC or named pipe issue...

Comment: `if (msg != null && msg.Length > 0)` => `if ( !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(msg) )`